# INotifyPropertyChanged-Feature on Auto-Properties

Tags: c#, mvvm, compiler-construction, aop, postsharp

I have many Model-Classes which implement the INotifyPropertyChanged-Interface in order to update the UI when value changed.

Sadly the properties must be written fully to support this feature. I decreased  my code already by using the 'SetPropertyValue'-Method() in BaseClass.

```
private string _title;
public string Title 
{
    get { return title; }
    set { SetPropertyValue("Title", ref _title, value ); }
}
```

But with 20 properties written like that in one file it is not so simple to understand the content of the file in a short time unlike to the auto implemented properties.

What I want is to write my Property like this:

```
[NotifyChanged]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

I checked already [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged) but in the free version there are only 10 classes included (it's a hobby project so I don't want to pay much money).

Is there any possibility to attach my one logic to C#-Compiler (as a pre-compiler)?
Such a feature I would like to use on different places in my code to reduce unneccessary coding lines (especially for auto-properties).

Or maybee a VisulStudio-Extension?

Comment: If/when doing MVVM you might want to reconsider binding the View to the Model. The View should only know about the ViewModel. So it is the ViewModel that should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I would just like to note that PostSharp `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` is not a trivial implementation. Notifications are not raised each time property is changed but only when control leaves the object's method. This has two benefits. First is performance; when you are doing more complex change, some properties tend to change multiple times. If you have other objects observing those properties and performing non-trivial calculations, performance can suffer. Second is atomicity; if you have a method that changes state of an object, notifications are not always fired in a valid state of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody). It is library which modifies IL code during build process using dedicated msbuild task.

It has large base of addins including [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which should suit in your scenario.
This addin gives you attribute ImplementPropertyChanged which you can apply to a class. Then Fody will generate code implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to all auto-properties.

[Second option](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/24/inotifypropertychanged-support-in-resharper-7/) if you have ReSharper version 7 or higher. It has refactoring which can help you with implementation of INotifyPropertyChanges. For example it can transform auto-property to "normal" property implementing the interface.
Thou it may not fully satisfy you - this approach may be interesting for you because it does not involve additional libraries and assembly modification.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/). The difference between `PostSharp` and `Fody` is that `DynamicProxy` generates its proxies on the fly at runtime.

Comment: In this case, there is no real benefit in having such proxies generated at runtime. You get worse startup performance and portability issues (on platforms where you cannot use create code at runtime).

Comment: @DanielBalas it's a valid answer, even though what you say is true, it is still simplifying the code (though i agree Fody is better here)